# I have created a wallpapers app using viewpager and urls of images but I am not able to set wallpapers I am placing my Urls in string

Tags: java, android

This is my mainactivity class and I am using my urls in the string. Anyone please tell me how to set wallpapers using multiple urls. I am using multiple urls to show in viewpager its working but I can't set wallpapers.

This is my main activity class.

I want to set wallpapers on floating button onclick listener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
            "https://i.jj.cc/MGTTwJ7Q/Ant-Man-474b00d1-4bdc-3ea6-88a3-1702c46f061c.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/SKvKN1dt/fdg-min.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/fLSR37gW/uhd-antman18-min.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/Gt0hvBZF/uhd-antman7-min.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/ryWpMJrQ/Antman-And-The-Wasp-d4a753af-1dd1-4df2-aeb6-d39c732fd16a.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/RVLVnZGt/uhd-antman21-min.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/t4RRdGmM/Ant-man-and-the-wasp-a294bb80-e6f9-41c1-bf46-07af64e3e348.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/y8f1vpMY/Antman-d8033f49-b33c-4cd4-b3ca-651417df20da.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/yNkV5XKh/Antman-Abstract-HD-05ef2c84-e5d3-41e9-afa1-1400c315bf06.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/8C91VJk2/IMG-0139.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/Znh4CGdj/antman-70390c1f-2d63-41ea-a487-e34668167e7e.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/vTLM907y/antman-2fde23ba-9eac-4f11-acf7-b872b9b71121.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/66dBDpkP/Antman-d353b93b-5c57-4363-ad92-4a974423d2b5.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/rFMqcLcw/Antman-df2e8adb-b0a0-42b6-ade7-38d041349ed1.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/YCSkGfvc/Antman-32cb0b83-f4b6-4a24-854a-913b593c0291.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/zGPNnbhy/razakbaap49.jpg",
            "https://i.jj.cc/tgZjDqd2/antman05-uhd.jpg"
    };

    private int indexOfImage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageChangeListener());

        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            MainActivity.this.indexOfImage = i;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    }
}
```

This is my viewpager adapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;


    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp)
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your url is correct or not. Hit url in web-browser.

Comment: its is correct @Shane. every thing is working fine but i am unable to set wallpapers thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Add this AsyncTask class in your MainActivity

```
public class SetWallpaper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = Picasso.get().load(params[0]).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading image...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Then try

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SetWallpaper sw = new SetWallpaper();
                sw.execute(imageUrls[indexOfImage])
            }
        });
```

Comment: what would be the code to set wallpapers which i can apply on floatingbutton on click method @Erwin Kurniawan

Comment: I just need the code to set my wallpapers by clicking the floating button @Erwin Kurniawan

Comment: @BagwanSohel Ya, i have added the code in my answer, have you try it?

Comment: yup i tried the code,wallpapers isnt set on screen just a black color @Erwin Kurniawan

Comment: Is your url image is correct? because i cant open one of your urls @BagwanSohel

Comment: yup urls are correct i just edited the link thats it. my ulrs are correct.my images are displayed in view pager correctly @Erwin Kurniawan

Comment: I have editted my answer again, should be works. @BagwanSohel

Comment: now the code work perfect and wallpapers are set @Erwin Kurniawan.What if i want to share and save images in local storage any hint or any code.

Comment: Glad to hear that. To save an image you may need to download your selected urls and set it to specific place @Bugs

Comment: I am Unable to share the wallpapers @Erwin Kurniawan. any code

Comment: how can i share the pictures @Erwin Kurniawan. i tried but i am unable . any help